# NSMutableDictionary problem in printing data

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have a problem with `NSMutableDictionary` I want to print all the keys in the dictionary.
I tried this.

```
for(id theKey in myDict) {
   NSLog(@"Key:%@-Value:%@",theKey,[myDict objectForKey:theKey]);
}
```

The above code is working. But i am getting the NSMutableDict from another controller. In that controller it has Data.But in new controller it is empty.
Guys Help? ... :]
@KennyTM:The code is here:

```
NewViewController *newCont = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
newCont.myDict = [myDict retain];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newCont animated:YES];
[sign release];
```

Comment: @KennyTM: Its printing nothing in the log.

Comment: @raj: Maybe `myDict` is empty?

Comment: @KennyTM: How to check whether dict is empty or not.

Comment: @raj: print this : `BOOL isEmpty = ([myDictcount] == 0);` to check if your dic is empty or not.

Comment: did you try just NSLog(@"%@", myDict)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. If you can't see anything in the log, it is possible that the dictionary is empty. You could check if a collection is empty using [the `-count` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/count).

```
if ([myDict count]==0) {
  // empty
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: @KennyTM: got it my dict is empty.

Comment: @KennyTM: I will explain the real problem. I am passing a NSMutableDict from one controller to another.In the new controller it is empty.Can u help ???

Comment: @raj: Doesn't look wrong. Are you sure `myDict` was not empty before the assignment? Also, have you `@synthesize myDict` in `NewViewController`?

Comment: @KennyTM:Got it. I didn't alloc and init it. But i started using it. Fixed my problem.Thanks a lot Kenny for being here. HAGD

Comment: synthesize  or property might be missing the pushed view controller

Comment: You should also check to make sure myDict is not nil